# mysql select if count of values for each user greater than 1

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table liked the following:

```
----------------------------
userId | artistId | trackId
----------------------------
user1  | artist1  | track1
-------|----------|--------
user1  | artist1  | track1
-------|----------|--------
user1  | artist1  | track1
-------|----------|--------
user2  | artist1  | track1
-------|----------|--------
user2  | artist2  | track2
-------|----------|--------
user2  | artist2  | track2
-------|----------|--------
 ....  |   ....   |  ....
```

What I need to do is: for each user, select those tracks that he listened more than once. So, e.g., in the table above, for user 1, it should return track1 (all 3 rows) and for user2 it should return only track2 (again all two rows).
I know how to count specific values of a column for each user, e.g. to count number of times each user listened to track1 and track2, I write this:

```
select userId,
  sum(case when trackId = 'track1' then 1 else 0 end) as track1_count,
  sum(case when trackId = 'track2' then 1 else 0 end) as track2_count
from populartracks_logs
group by userId
```

But since my table is big (about 5 million rows) with many tracks, I don't know how to select (FOR EACH USER) those tracks that are repeated for that specific user more than once. Could someone please help me?

Thanks,

Comment: `group by userid, trackid`, then. the sum/case business is pointless when you could do what you want by simply adding another `group` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve all lines, you'll need a subquery, and a join on it (you may add artistId in the inner query, group by and join clause)

```
select userId, trackId, artistId
from populartracks_logs p
join
   (select userId, trackId
    from populartracks_logs
    group by userId, trackId
    having count(*) > 1) as m
  on m.userId = p.userId and p.trackID = m.trackId
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit why join is needed? you can include artistid in group by, get the same result, much faster

Comment: @Lashane The question mentions : retrieve all 3 rows (resp. all 2 rows) by group if there's more than one. Group by would return only one line by "group".

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus you're right, I've missed this part of question, still cannot understand why OP needs to fetch duplicated rows, probably just to use more network

Comment: @Lashane: I need all the rows (It seems they are duplicates, but in fact, they are related to different timestamps). So, each row shows a separate time when user listened to the tracks (even for same tracks)

Answer (score 4):

quite simple query:

```
select userId, trackId
from populartracks_logs
group by userId, trackId
having count(*) > 1
```

note having clause